# Как поменять цвет текста JButton, когда она заблокирована?

Tags: java, swing, button

Пример:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Window();
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {
    JButton button;
    Window(){
        button = new JButton("Text");
        button.setForeground(Color.RED);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        this.add(button);
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

В итоге выполнения данной программы текст кнопки будет серого цвета. Как сделать так, чтобы цвет стал таким, каким я захочу, при этом кнопка должна быть заблокирована?

Comment: О, в кои-то веки вопрос с МСВП, +1! В английской версии есть вариант с HTML, попробуйте: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318537/change-jbuttons-disabled-foreground-font-color-for-windows

Comment: Да, я сначала и там поискал, но тот вариант с html   мне не подошёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, текст цвета недоступного элемента задается текущим Look and Feel.

Изменить его можно глобально через [`UIManager.getDefaults`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getDefaults--) по ключу `Button.disabledText`:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.disabledText", Color.MAGENTA);
```

Также можно установить свой объект `UI` для конкретной кнопки и переопределить метод [`MetalButtonUI.getDisabledTextColor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalButtonUI.html#getDisabledTextColor--):

```
button.setUI(new MetalButtonUI() {
    protected Color getDisabledTextColor() {
        return Color.MAGENTA;
    }
});
```

Приведенные способы могут не сработать если используется нестандартный Look and Feel.